# ionic versioning not working in the browser platform

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

Is there any way to read ionic 3 application version for all platforms(android, ios and web)?

I tried with [cordova-plugin-app-version](https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version).

```
this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then(response => {
    console.log('App version', response);
})
```

Version is not shown in browser.

You can read version from package.json like this:

```
 const environment = {
          VERSION: require('../../../package.json').version
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is by having a global variable app_version declared in the index.html that I update everytime I make a new version. That globale variable is then accessible everywhere in your app regardless of what platform you are in.

In your index.html :

```
<script>
var app_version = require('../package.json').version;
</script>
```

Then in any page or component where you need to use it Just add this before @Component(...) declaration :

```
declare const app_version;
```

app_version is now available to be assigned to a component property and displayed if necessary;

Comment: that's the oone way to do it but I would like to read version from package.json

Comment: I have updated my answer to read the version from package.json